# What is the maximum number of bounces a ball can be expected to make on another fixed ball of same radius on the ground?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle

In the book 'Quantum Mechanics' by Leonard I. Schiff, this question can be found at the end of chapter one. More specifically it asks:

A perfectly elastic ping pong ball is dropped in vacuum from a height equal to ten times its radius onto a perfectly elastic fixed sphere of the same radius. Neglecting effect due to Earth's motion, estimate the largest number of bounces against the fixed sphere that the ball can be expected to make under optimum condition of release.

Classically this should be infinite, but that can't be the result here. Perhaps Heisenberg's uncertainty principle for angular momentum can be used. I have tried calculating an approximated result which was huge therefore I am not quite sure if I am working in the right direction.

If someone can solve it or at least point towards a good direction, I would be thankful.

Comment: Having done this demonstration many times, the practical answer is **once**.  The top ball invariably bounces at some angle to the vertical, never to land again on the bottom ball.  However, I don't think that's what this textbook intended for an answer!

Comment: Classically I found that the angle (using simple projectile trajectory equations) from the vertical was around 0.716° to an approximation. Then I loosely tried applying Heisenberg's uncertainty in the angle related to the angular momentum. For one bounce the ball would at the very minimum move up to the prescribed uncertain angle. So if I reiterate these steps again and again I should get a number of bounce after which this ball crosses 0.716°. However that with some approximation brings me a huge result. So I am a bit skeptical.

Comment: How do you get that angle?

Answer (score -1):

Thinking of a particle bound by an infinite barrier (the ball on the ground) and a potential that varies with height (gravity), maybe the ball eventually bounces out of the potential by tunnelling, i.e. calculate the probability.